# How to increase error bar width using stat_summary (ggplot2) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, width

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-stripchart-jitter-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) to plot a stripchart with error bars, but I'm being unable to control bar width.

```
# Convert the variable dose from a numeric to a factor variable
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

# Plot
ggplot(data = ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len, color = dose)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2), size = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "pointrange", size = 1.2)
```

When I add the argument `width = 2`, R returns:

```
Warning message:
In stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "pointrange", size = 1.2, :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: width
```

How could I control the width of these error bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `linewidth = 2` ?

```r
ggplot(data = ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len, color = dose)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2), size = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "pointrange", size = 1.2, linewidth = 2)
```

[image]